# Mysql insert null datetime in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert a null datetime value into a mysql server using JavaScript and nodejs.

It was working perfectly when I was using ? SET as it was keeping the value as a null object, however when trying to use UPDATE it seems to be converting it to a string and failing:

```
data = {id :123, type: 'test', date: (a datetime object)}

connection.query('INSERT INTO table SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' +
    ' type=\'' + data.type + '\',' +
    ' date=\'' + data.date + '\',' +
    ' ', data, (err) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Success");
    }
    else
        console.log(err);
});
```

If there is no duplicate key the null datetime inserts fine as it keeps the formatting - but I don't know how to avoid making it a string here?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following solution:

```
if (job.close_date == null) {
        close_date = '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
    }
```

But it seems quite messy